# Google Drive mapped to letter links instead to user directory

Tags: windows-10, google-drive

I have two Windows 10 Pro PCs. On both, there are multiple google drive accounts, but one in particular is shared by both.

How can I make it so that on both PCs I can access the files via a dedicated drive letter without linking to Users' directory?

---

On one PC, I can access the files via a drive letter `G:\My Drive\some folder...`

Here "Můj disk" means "My Drive"
[image]

```
G:\>dir /A
 Volume in drive G is a...@gmail.com - Goog...
 Volume Serial Number is 1983-1116

 Directory of G:\

09.03.2023  23:44    <DIR>          .file-revisions-by-id
09.03.2023  23:44    <DIR>          Můj disk
09.03.2023  23:44    <DIR>          .shortcut-targets-by-id
09.03.2023  23:44    <DIR>          $RECYCLE.BIN
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               4 Dir(s)   6 621 237 248 bytes free

G:\>ls -la
ls: Muj disk: No such file or directory
total 0
drwxrwxrwx   1 user     group           0 Mar  9 23:44 $RECYCLE.BIN
drwxrwxrwx   1 user     group           0 Mar  9 23:44 .file-revisions-by-id
drwxrwxrwx   1 user     group           0 Mar  9 23:44 .shortcut-targets-by-id
```

*note: The output of ls `ls: Muj disk: No such file or directory` is somewhat sus.*

However, on the other PC, attempting to open `G:\My Drive` now instead opens `C:\Users\Qwerty\Google Drive`.

[image]

```
G:\>dir /A
 Volume in drive G is a...@gmail.com - Goog...
 Volume Serial Number is 1983-1116

 Directory of G:\

10.03.2023  00:10    <DIR>          .shortcut-targets-by-id
10.03.2023  00:10    <DIR>          .file-revisions-by-id
10.03.2023  00:10    <DIR>          $RECYCLE.BIN
10.03.2023  00:10               747 My Drive.lnk
               1 File(s)            747 bytes
               3 Dir(s)   6 621 200 384 bytes free

G:\>la
total 5
drwxr-xr-x 0 Qwerty 197609   0 Mar 10 00:10 '$RECYCLE.BIN'
drwxr-xr-x 0 Qwerty 197609   0 Mar 10 00:10  .
drwxr-xr-x 1 Qwerty 197609   0 Sep  3  2022  ..
drwxr-xr-x 0 Qwerty 197609   0 Mar 10 00:10  .file-revisions-by-id
drwxr-xr-x 0 Qwerty 197609   0 Mar 10 00:10  .shortcut-targets-by-id
-rwxr-xr-x 0 Qwerty 197609 747 Mar 10 00:10 'My Drive.lnk'
```

"My Drive" is not a directory but a `*.lnk` file instead.

How can I make it so that it works as a drive as in previous example?

Comment: Instead of [tag:google-drive] use [tag:google-drive-filestream]. According to the tag excerpt, the first is for questions about desktop client that is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make it so that it works as a drive

On the machine **with the issue while signed on**, go to the system tray, and **click on the Google Drive** icon to bring up the window with the gear icon first.

> [image]

---

1. Next, click on the **gear** icon

   [image]
2. Select **Google Drive (Folder from Drive)** option
3. Select **Stream files** option

   [image]

### Supporting Resource

- [Use Google Drive for desktop](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/10838124?hl=en)

Comment: You do not want to **Mirror files** basically, you want to **Stream files** to get the desired result to make those accessible via a mounted drive letter from Windows.

Comment: When I noticed the issue, I went to the settings on the correct machine and it was indeed turned to "**Stream files**" so I changed it to "**Mirror files**" which I use on the other one, but even after the change, the files are still accessible via a mounted drive without redirecting to user directory.

Comment: Though, I just noticed that while browsing, all of the files and folders still display the cloud overlay, suggesting that they are only available online. Right-clicking confirms that. What is interesting too is that on the other machine, the context menu misses the option for offline access.

Comment: Ah, alright, I see what the issue was. While the settings (on your 2nd screenshot the cogwheel on top right) is for all accounts, the "Google Drive" option on left is only for a selected account-makes sense, but it was unexpected for me. Switching the account revealed that it was still using streaming. Trying to change that now prompts to choose a folder outside of the drive.

This brings a question: **What if I used "available offline" for the whole "G:\My Drive", while still using streaming?**. How would that be different from mirroring?